# maven error with my pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I get the below maven error when I ran my project. Can you please let me know what is wrong in my pom.xml . Thanks in advance I am using the latest version of maven. I have added the required repositories too. Does it require any changes  like adding a new repository?

[image]

When I tried with mvn clean install -U. I got the below error

[image]

Below is my pom.xml

```
                <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
              <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
              <groupId>Survey</groupId>
              <artifactId>Survey</artifactId>
              <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <packaging>war</packaging>
              <name>Survey</name>
              <build>
                <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
                <resources>
                  <resource>
                    <directory>src</directory>
                    <excludes>
                      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                  </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                  <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <source>1.6</source>
                      <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>
                  <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </plugin>
                </plugins>
              </build>
              <repositories>
              <repository>
                  <id>tanesha</id>
                  <name>tanesha repository</name>
                  <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.tanesha.recaptcha4j/recaptcha4j</url>
              </repository>
               <repository>
                  <id>activation</id>
                  <name>activation repository</name>
                  <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation</url>
              </repository>
              <repository>
                  <id>simplecaptcha</id>
                  <name>simplecaptcha repository</name>
                  <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nl.captcha/simplecaptcha</url>
              </repository>
              </repositories>
                 <dependencies>
                    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> 
                        <version>${jackson.version}</version> </dependency> -->
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                                <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                                <version>1.4</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                                <version>1.8.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                                <version>3.2.2</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
                                <version>0.2</version>
                            </dependency>                            
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                                <version>1.3.2</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                                <version>2.2</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                                <version>2.4</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                                <version>3.2</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                                <version>1.1.1</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                                <version>1.1.3</version>
                            </dependency>   
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                                <version>1.1</version>
                            </dependency>   
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                                <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                                <artifactId>displaytag-export-poi</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
                                <artifactId>displaytag-portlet</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.22</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                                <version>4.0.1</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                                <version>3.0</version>
                            </dependency>                   
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                                <version>3.11.0.GA</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.4</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                                <version>3.1.0</version>
                            </dependency>                       
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
                                <version>1.1</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2</version>
                            </dependency>               
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>ognl</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
                                <version>3.0.19</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <!-- <dependency>
                                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                                <version>11.2.0.3</version>
                            </dependency> -->
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>net.tanesha.recaptcha4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>recaptcha4j</artifactId>
                                <version>0.0.7</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
                                <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
                                <version>1.3</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>nl.captcha</groupId>
                                <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2.1</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                                <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                                <version>1.1.2</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                                <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.30</version>
                            </dependency>               
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
                                <version>1.6.2</version>
                            </dependency>
                             <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
                                <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.30</version>
                            </dependency>                               
                  </dependencies>
            </project>
```

Below is my settings.xml

```
                                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                    <!--
                    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
                    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
                    distributed with this work for additional information
                    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
                    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
                    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
                    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

                        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

                    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
                    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
                    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
                    KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
                    specific language governing permissions and limitations
                    under the License.
                    -->

                    <!--
                     | This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:
                     |
                     |  1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user, 
                     |                 and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
                     |
                     |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
                     |
                     |                 -s /path/to/user/settings.xml
                     |
                     |  2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all Maven
                     |                 users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven
                     |                 installation). It's normally provided in 
                     |                 ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml.
                     |
                     |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
                     |
                     |                 -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml
                     |
                     | The sections in this sample file are intended to give you a running start at
                     | getting the most out of your Maven installation. Where appropriate, the default
                     | values (values used when the setting is not specified) are provided.
                     |
                     |-->
                    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                              xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
                      <!-- localRepository
                       | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
                       |
                       | Default: ~/.m2/repository
                      <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
                      -->

                      <!-- interactiveMode
                       | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,
                       | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for
                       | the parameter in question.
                       |
                       | Default: true
                      <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
                      -->

                      <!-- offline
                       | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.
                       | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
                       |
                       | Default: false
                      <offline>false</offline>
                      -->

                      <!-- pluginGroups
                       | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.
                       | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
                       | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.
                       |-->
                      <pluginGroups>
                        <!-- pluginGroup
                         | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
                        <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
                        -->
                      </pluginGroups>

                      <!-- proxies
                       | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
                       | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
                       | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
                       |-->
                      <proxies>
                        <!-- proxy
                         | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
                         |
                        <proxy>
                          <id>optional</id>
                          <active>true</active>
                          <protocol>http</protocol>
                          <username>proxyuser</username>
                          <password>proxypass</password>
                          <host>proxy.host.net</host>
                          <port>80</port>
                          <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
                        </proxy>
                        -->
                      </proxies>

                      <!-- servers
                       | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
                       | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
                       |-->
                      <servers>
                        <!-- server
                         | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by
                         | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).
                         | 
                         | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are 
                         |       used together.
                         |
                        <server>
                          <id>deploymentRepo</id>
                          <username>repouser</username>
                          <password>repopwd</password>
                        </server>
                        -->

                        <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.
                        <server>
                          <id>siteServer</id>
                          <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
                          <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
                        </server>
                        -->
                      </servers>

                      <!-- mirrors
                       | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts from remote repositories.
                       | 
                       | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository to use in resolving certain artifacts.
                       | However, this repository may have problems with heavy traffic at times, so people have mirrored
                       | it to several places.
                       |
                       | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create a mirror reference for that
                       | repository, to be used as an alternate download site. The mirror site will be the preferred 
                       | server for that repository.
                       |-->
                      <mirrors>
                        <!-- mirror
                         | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
                         | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
                         | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
                         |
                        <mirror>
                          <id>mirrorId</id>
                          <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
                          <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
                          <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
                        </mirror>
                         -->
                      </mirrors>

                      <!-- profiles
                       | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety of ways, and which can modify
                       | the build process. Profiles provided in the settings.xml are intended to provide local machine-
                       | specific paths and repository locations which allow the build to work in the local environment.
                       |
                       | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus - that needs to know where
                       | your Tomcat instance is installed, you can provide a variable here such that the variable is 
                       | dereferenced during the build process to configure the cactus plugin.
                       |
                       | As noted above, profiles can be activated in a variety of ways. One way - the activeProfiles
                       | section of this document (settings.xml) - will be discussed later. Another way essentially
                       | relies on the detection of a system property, either matching a particular value for the property,
                       | or merely testing its existence. Profiles can also be activated by JDK version prefix, where a 
                       | value of '1.4' might activate a profile when the build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'.
                       | Finally, the list of active profiles can be specified directly from the command line.
                       |
                       | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to specifying only artifact
                       |       repositories, plugin repositories, and free-form properties to be used as configuration
                       |       variables for plugins in the POM.
                       |
                       |-->
                      <profiles>
                        <!-- profile
                         | Specifies a set of introductions to the build process, to be activated using one or more of the
                         | mechanisms described above. For inheritance purposes, and to activate profiles via <activatedProfiles/>
                         | or the command line, profiles have to have an ID that is unique.
                         |
                         | An encouraged best practice for profile identification is to use a consistent naming convention
                         | for profiles, such as 'env-dev', 'env-test', 'env-production', 'user-jdcasey', 'user-brett', etc.
                         | This will make it more intuitive to understand what the set of introduced profiles is attempting
                         | to accomplish, particularly when you only have a list of profile id's for debug.
                         |
                         | This profile example uses the JDK version to trigger activation, and provides a JDK-specific repo.
                        <profile>
                          <id>jdk-1.4</id>

                          <activation>
                            <jdk>1.4</jdk>
                          </activation>

                          <repositories>
                            <repository>
                              <id>jdk14</id>
                              <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
                              <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
                              <layout>default</layout>
                              <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
                            </repository>
                          </repositories>
                        </profile>
                        -->

                        <!--
                         | Here is another profile, activated by the system property 'target-env' with a value of 'dev',
                         | which provides a specific path to the Tomcat instance. To use this, your plugin configuration
                         | might hypothetically look like:
                         |
                         | ...
                         | <plugin>
                         |   <groupId>org.myco.myplugins</groupId>
                         |   <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>
                         |   
                         |   <configuration>
                         |     <tomcatLocation>${tomcatPath}</tomcatLocation>
                         |   </configuration>
                         | </plugin>
                         | ...
                         |
                         | NOTE: If you just wanted to inject this configuration whenever someone set 'target-env' to
                         |       anything, you could just leave off the <value/> inside the activation-property.
                         |
                        <profile>
                          <id>env-dev</id>

                          <activation>
                            <property>
                              <name>target-env</name>
                              <value>dev</value>
                            </property>
                          </activation>

                          <properties>
                            <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>
                          </properties>
                        </profile>
                        -->
                      </profiles>

                      <!-- activeProfiles
                       | List of profiles that are active for all builds.
                       |
                      <activeProfiles>
                        <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
                        <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
                      </activeProfiles>
                      -->

                    </settings>
```

Comment: can you try with `mvn clean install -U`. -U is for force update.

Comment: can you paste your settings.xml, please? So we can see which repositories you're using

Comment: added my settings.xml file

Comment: Does this computer have internet connection? Or does your network have some sort of proxy ?

Comment: Remove the configuration which mention `https://mvnrepository.com` as repository. This is wrong. It is needed having internet connection.

Comment: @khmarbaise Remove https://mvnrepository.com form my pom.xml?

Comment: Yes...please....do not use in settings.xml etc. cause it's not a maven repository.

Comment: Where have add the dependency `javax.activation:activation:1.0.2` cause this dependency is simply wrong and does not exist or to be more accurate it does not has a jar file in maven central? You have `javassist: javassist` with two different versions in your pom that will not work..You must make a decision which version to use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the fix for this issue

Sun will not allow Maven to redistribute its binaries, including JavaMail JAR and Activation JAR. Instead, all users must install Sun binaries manually by downloading them from Sun's website and running the mvn install command.

1. Download Java Activation Framework

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jaf-136260.html

and then

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jaf/1.0.2-fcs/jaf-1_0_2-upd2.zip

2. Extract "jaf-1.0.2"
3. Run at folder "jaf-1.0.2"

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=activation.jar -DgroupId=javax.activation -DartifactId=activation -Dversion=1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar

Comment: This changed a long time ago and these artifacts are available in Maven Central. E.g. for JavaMail: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.sun.mail%22%20AND%20a%3A%22javax.mail%22.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>enonic</id>
        <url>http://repo.enonic.com/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the repositories tag from the pom.

If this doesn't resolve the issue,

1. Delete javax.activation and net.tanesha.recaptcha4j  folder from your local maven repository.
2. Delete the .cache folder in local maven repository.
3. Force update maven dependencies using -U option.

   mvn clean install -U

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I change my repository url?  Do I need to change it in my pom.xml?

Comment: Yes. And before that try by removing it entirely since mavenrepository.com is a central repository and should be able to access with default configuration.

Comment: How do I remove it entirely. You want me to remove it entirely from pom.xml . ?

Comment: Yes. Remove the <repositories> tag completely.

Comment: Simply wrong, cause `https://mvnrepository.com/` is only search engine but **not** maven central. There is no need to configure maven central explicit it's configured by default in Maven.

Comment: Hmm. I see. Updated the answer.

Comment: I did everything you told. It still gives me the same error